# Transient, Positive Recurrent, or Null Recurrent

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

\begin{align}
P_{1, 2^i} = 2^{-i} ~~&\textrm{and} ~~P_{i+1, i}= 1, ~i\in \mathbb Z^+\\P_{i, 1} = 1/(i+1) ~~&\textrm{and}~~ P_{i, i+1} = I/(I+1), ~i \in \mathbb Z^+.
\end{align}

Given the following sets of transition probabilities, how do I determine whether the irreducible DTMC is transient, positive recurrent or null recurrent?

So I understand that the state is positive recurrent iff its mean recurrent time < infinity, and null recurrent iff its mean recurrent time = infinity. Although how do you determine this given the transition probabilities?

Comment: Just determine the mean recurrence time for state $1$.  It goes to states $2, 4, 8, 16, \ldots$ with probabilities $1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, \ldots$, then from there they go back to $1$ one step at a time.  For example, with probability $1/4$, state $1$ recurs after four steps: $1, 4, 3, 2, 1$.  Sum up the expected time over all cases (an infinite sum).  What do you get?

Comment: Just saying to avoid confusion both statements are 2 different DTMC's not the same one!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my comment was meant specifically just for the first row.  The principle still applies to the second row; the algebra is different, of course.

Answer (score 1):

**Recurrence vs Transience of Markov Chains**

We say that an irreducible chain is recurrent, if the return time from some state state to itself is finite almost surely (and transient otherwise). Without loss of generality, you can pick any state, since if the chain is recurrent, any two states can get to each other in finite time.

Let's look at the two chains you gave:

Let $X_0 = 1$. To show that $\mathbb{P}(\tau < \infty) = 1$, let us note that if $X_1 = 2^n$, then $\tau = 2^n + 1$. So, $P(\tau > 2^n) = \sum_{i=n}^\infty 2^{-i} = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$. So, by Borel-Cantelli, we know that only finitely many of the events $ \{ A_{2^i} \}_{i=1}^\infty$ will happen, which means $\tau$ is finite almost surely. (Alternatively, you can observe that $P(\tau > 2^n) \rightarrow 0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and then noting that $\{ \tau =. \infty  \} \subset \{ \tau > 2^n \}$ )

For the second chain, let $Y_0 = 1$. Now, $P(\tau > n) = \Pi_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{i+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}$. From here, with the argument as before, you can conclude recurrence.

**Recurrent null vs positive recurrence**

For this, we will look at the expected return time from some state, and we will say that a chain is recurrent null if the return time is infinite, and positive recurrent otherwise. Much like before, we can look at any state, since if the expected return time for one state is finite, it must be that it is finite for all the states that link to it. so let us do that for the two examples:

Let $X_0 = 1$ as before.

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\tau] &= \sum_i P(X_1 = i) \mathbb{E}[\tau \mid X_1 = i]\\
&= \sum_i 2^{-i} (2^i+1) \\
&\geq \sum_i 1 = \infty   
\end{align*}

For the second one,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\tau] &= \sum_i P(\tau > i) \\
&= \sum_i \frac{1}{i+1} \\  
\end{align*}

which is a divergent sum.

Comment: OP seems to have double posted the second problem which I answered, here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752875/dtmc-random-walk .  There is t typo in that link regarding probabilities that OP refused to correct for whatever reason.

Comment: Yeah seems like somewhat of a duplicate. Since this question remained unanswered,  they reposted. Do we merge them/flag the question? TBH the main reason why I answered this one was to help the other answerer of this post.