# DTMC Random Walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk, probability-limit-theorems

> $P_{i,1}=\frac{i}{i+1}$ and $P_{i,i+1}=\frac{i}{i+1},i\in\mathbb{Z}$

Can someone walk me through how to prove this DTMC Random Walk scenario is either transient, null recurrent or positive recurrent? I have read countless posts and different notes in textbooks and cannot figure out how to go about properly showing this. I simply start by i=1 and notice a pattern and try and disprove it being positive recurrent then prove transient or null recurrent but I am truly struggling..

Comment: $\sum_j P_{i,j}$ should be 1

Comment: +1 for the above comment, also I observe that $-1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ but the case $i=-1$ leads to $0$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

after cleaning up some open typos, I infer that you'll have probabilities $p_k\in(0,1)$
$P :=\left(\begin{matrix}
1-p_1 & p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_2 & 0 & p_2& 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_3 & 0 & 0 & p_3 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_4 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_5 & \dots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{matrix}\right)$

which is known as the (renewal) *Age Matrix* and is discussed in some detail in Feller vol 1 (3rd ed) Markov Chains chapter.

By inspection there is a single communicating class.

To verify transience/ recurrence, you merely need to check for state 1.  And you don't return WP1 to state one *iff*
$\prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k \gt 0$.
Sums are easier to evaluate than products, so use the below identity, with $\delta_k = 1-p_k$
[$\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-1/2^k)$ converge to zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3532080/prod-k-1-infty-1-1-2k-converge-to-zero/3532167#3532167)

If the chain is transient, then you are done.  If the chain is recurrent, then you may evaluate  positive recurrence by simply checking whether the mean time until revisiting state 1 is finite.   This may be computed directly as
$E\big[T\big] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P\big(T\gt k\big) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \prod_{j=1}^k p_j$

Comment: Okay so then would that make this DTMC transient?

Comment: hard to say, the OP still says "$P_{i,1}=\frac{i}{i+1}$ and $P_{i,i+1}=\frac{i}{i+1},i\in\mathbb{Z}$"... as pointed out in the comments this needs edited... but I'd guess there's a divergent harmonic series at play.

Comment: What is the problem with that?

Comment: $P_{i,i+1} + P_{i,1} = \frac{2i}{i+1}\gt 1$ for $i\geq 2$ and it should be something like $i\in \mathbb N$ not integers